# Resolve path to xlst file in Windows Azure

Tags: azure

Im planning to code a web app in azure and im having a question... 
For sending emails I use a class library that I wrote some time ago, I have the email template in an xlst file and every time I want to send an email I create an object with the information that I want to include in the email, I serialize that object to xml and transform it to an email in html format using the xlst file.

This has worked great for me and I want to use it in my Azure web app. The question that I have is, how can I locate the xlst file? Should I mark it as "Content" in the properties tab? How can I access it?

Thanks in advance,
Juan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As smarx already pointed out, `Server.MapPath` will work if you have the file uploaded at deploy and not changed by the application.

In our applications, we solve this using [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). In the class library, we would define an interface, e.g. `ITemplateRepository` with no implementation. In the project where you need the class library, you create the implementation of that interface and because that is in the web app you can safely use Server.MapPath, or go to Azure blob storage or do basically anything else.

While we use DI we simply have constructors that look like this:

```
public TemplatedMailService(ITemplateRepository repo) {
    this._repo = repo;
}
```

If you aren't using a DI container you can just do this:

```
var myService = new ClassLibrary.TemplatedMailService(new WebProject.ServerStoragezrepository());
```

This would be the most extensible way. But do also look into DI.

Comment: On a side note, if you want the user to be able to specify custom templates, the repository will need both Get and Put methods. But in that case you shouldn't use local folder structure to do it and should instead use Azure Blob Storage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, marking the file as "content" and then finding it via Server.MapPath("~/whatever.xslt") should work fine. (This is presumably what you would do in a normal web application, right?)

Comment: I would like to have the class that sends the emails in a class library.... And if I want something reusable, that would not be the solution right? I mean, in a normal server I could have the absolute path to the folder where the xslt files are. But here, how would it work? If I use Server.MapPath, it would work for a web site, but not for a worker role... right?

Comment: Well, the file has to go somewhere. On a normal server, you're saying you would just hardcode a path? How would you get the file there in the first place? Of course, if it's always the same file, you could just make it a resource of your class library instead.